# Le verbe « aider » à l'impératif

Tags: impératif

Si on dit « aider quelqu'un à faire quelque chose » pourquoi alors  dit-on à l'impératif « aide-lui » et pas « aide-le » ? On n'applique pas la régle du COD dans ce cas-là ?

Answer (score 4):

Vous faites erreur: A l'impératif, on ne dit pas "**aide lui**" mais "**aide-le**". N'omettez pas le trait d'union ("-") qui est obligatoire entre le verbe et le COD à l'impératif.

Answer (score 2):

Justement, le pronom complément d'objet direct est « le », donc « quelqu'un » étant cod dans cette locution, pour dire « aider quelqu'un » sans nommer cette personne de nouveau on dit bien « aide-le » ; on ne dit jamais « aide-lui ». Lorsque le verbe n'est pas transitif « lui » est utilisé. Mais attention, tout cela est totalement indépendant du mode ; le mode n'a rien à voir dans ces principes.

- commander **à** quelqu'un ■ Commande-lui de sortir.
- dire **à** quelqu'un ■ Dis-lui de partir.

Answer (score 2):

Les verbes d'assistance et de gêne (comme aider, empêcher, stopper ou gêner) se construisaient initialement avec un complément datif et cette structure persiste ça et là:

- Soit dans la langue littéraire ancienne ou ses imitations  (Chateaubriand, *M. des Lourdines*, 1911: "[..]occupation à quoi sans doute **lui aidaient** ses souvenirs")
- Soit régionalement, le Québec et la zone de substrat franco-provençal étant réputés utiliser la forme avec objet indirect pour aider, par example.
- Que l'objet soit un pronom tend à favoriser la variante indirecte même hors des regions précitées, j'entends assez régulièrement des formes comme "Il a voulu **lui empêcher** d'entrer".

Un "aide-lui" lu ou entendu au passage n'a donc rien d'étonnant, même si "aide-le/-la" reste plus courant.

Answer (score 2):

Complément aux réponses :

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2885

> La construction avec complément indirect aider à quelqu’un était
>   courante aux XVIIe et XVIIIe siècles. Elle a été supplantée dans
>   l’usage standard actuel par la construction directe aider quelqu’un,
>   mais elle reste encore répandue en français régional de même qu’au
>   Québec et en Acadie.
>   Selon la norme grammaticale actuelle, il est donc préférable de faire suivre le verbe aider d’un complément direct lorsqu’il s’agit d’une personne.
>
> (...) En revanche, la construction aider à peut être employée lorsque le complément n’est pas une personne; aider à quelque chose, c’est « contribuer à la réalisation de cette chose ». De même, on a aider à lorsque le complément est un verbe à l’infinitif.
>
> Il est intéressant d’observer que aider quelque chose et aider à
>   quelque chose sont tous deux possibles mais que l’on pourra
>   privilégier une forme ou l’autre selon ce que le complément désigne.
>   Ainsi, on recourra naturellement à la construction transitive
>   indirecte lorsque le complément est un substantif d’action; on dira
>   aider à la reconstruction ou à la mise en œuvre de quelque chose, mais
>   aider la nature, la classe moyenne. Cette distinction n’opère
>   cependant pas toujours et il y a des cas où les deux formes sont
>   équivalentes, par exemple : aider à la digestion ou aider la
>   digestion.
>
> En plus d’un complément direct, aider peut également avoir d’autres compléments introduits par les prépositions dans, pour, de ou par : aider quelqu’un dans son malheur, dans son travail, pour une soirée, aider quelqu’un de ses conseils, par ses actions, etc.